# AWS Webhook custom template results in 403 when going to sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks, amazon-sqs

I am running into a strange problem whilst trying to leveraging a custom mapping template in my webhook which has an integration with an SQS service.

As I understand it, the purpose of the mapping template is to massage the data that the webhook has received before it passes it off to the next integration (be it SQS, lambda, etc). If I keep it as a plain pass through as so:

`Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body`

Everything works fine, no transformation occurs and my message is appropriately dropped to my queue. However, I would like to massage the data some if possible. The data comes from sendgrid, and in this case could be a set of events relating to the email (ex: it was delivered, processed, etc.) As such I know it is an array. I tried the following:

```
#set($sendgridEvents= $util.parseJson($input.body))
[
    #foreach($sendgridEvent in $sendgridEvents)
    {
            Action=SendMessage&MessageBody={
            "test_variable": "$sendgridEvent.EntityId"
            }
        
    }#if($foreach.hasNext), #end
    #end
]
```

If I run the following, I can see that my transformation happens correctly:

```
...
Thu Nov 30 20:02:16 UTC 2023 : Endpoint request body after transformations: [
        {
            Action=SendMessage&MessageBody={
            "test_variable": "Entity-Id-2323232"
            }
        
    }    ]
...
```

This made me think, okay, perhaps it is the fact I have the SendMessage in it and it is treating it as part of the object. I tried removing that and just keeping it as:

```
#set($sendgridEvents= $util.parseJson($input.body))
[
    #foreach($sendgridEvent in $sendgridEvents)
    {
            
            "test_variable": "$sendgridEvent.EntityId"
            
        
    }#if($foreach.hasNext), #end
    #end
]
```

and I still get a 403 access denied to my SQS even though if I keep it as just a regular ol' pass through as I did at the top, everything works fine. What exactly am I missing here? I looked at the docs, but for a trillion dollar company Amazon's AWS has some of the WORST documentation known to mankind. JavaDocs are positively usable in comparison.